# How can i change android actionbar picture

Tags: java, android-studio, android-actionbar

i am new on android and i am using android studio to develop. i want to change actionbar top right corner button image to another one but after compile to my android device the button still remain the ... but my customize image. please help!! below is my code. my public class is extend activity.

menu.xml

```
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Comment: Are you trying to put a new action button on your action bar or are you trying to change the overflow icon (usually three vertical dots is the default)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the Action Overflow Icon - default is three vertical dots - you have to add an actionOverflowButtonStyle item to your main theme declaration **AND** then define it in styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- base application theme -->
    <style 
        name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <!-- include overflow style in theme -->
       <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlowIcon</item>
    </style>

    <!-- styles -->
    <style 
        name="OverFlowIcon"     
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_search_black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Of course if you're using AppCompat themes don't forget to use atributes **without** the android namespace or it wont work - ie

```
<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
```

instead of what you see above.

Also don't forget to include your theme in application tag of AndroidManifest.xml if you change make a custom theme:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.android.MainApp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks Burkely91. Your Solution save my time. Its work.

Comment: Hi Burkely, after i change the image. do you know how it always show drop down list ? cause i want use to press actionbar button to open camera but it always me dropdown list.

Comment: @vic3ai I posted another answer below that should hopefully help!

Answer (score 2):

Vic3ai, That icon all the way to the right is the *Action Overflow* and it will always show a drop down list of action buttons that don't fit on the actionbar (either because there isn't room or because we decided to put some in the overflow on purpose).

This might give you a better idea of what the overflow is and is used for, as well as a general overview of the actionbar - http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html.

It sounds like what you actually want is to add an *action button* to your action bar. You can do that like so:

First add a new item in your menu.xml for which ever activity you want it to appear in:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/camera_button"
    android:title="@string/camera"
    android:icon="@drawable/camera_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always" 
     />
```

Here the important thing is android:showAsAction="always". This is what makes it appear as an action button on the action bar. You could also use value 'ifRoom', which does what it says on the tin: If there's room on the actionbar the button will display, otherwise it goes into the action overflow.

Now that we have the actionbutton in existence we go to our actvity.java and respond to the button:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.camera_button:
            //your code here, eg:
            openCamera(); 
            return true;
     // if you have other buttons, more cases would go here

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

So far this should give you an Action Button on the actionbar that will run whatever could you define in your activity.java but the *action overflow* will still be there. The easiest way to remove it is to go back to your menu.xml and remove/change any items that would appear in the overflow.

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

will automatically put action in to the overflow

If you have a lot of action buttons and any of them have **android:showAsAction="ifRoom"**, you might find an overflow button on the far right again

NOTE, use **app:showAsAction="always"** instead of android namespace if you're using appCompat compatibility.

Hope this helps!